# error ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle

Currently, I'm facing the error "ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" when trying to login on my front end. Every solution I've seen so far was to change the service_name on tnsnames.ora, but I've checked on my command line and the service name is correct. Yesterday, this was working fine, but I've encountered this issue before (I think my previous fix was to change the host name, but that is already correct this time).
Since I'm new to this, I don't fully know what other data I should be providing but let me know if any further info is needed.

Thank you :)

This is my tnsnames.ora.

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

And my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PROLTPE15G4PS.Home)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure the database is up - can you connect with other methods? If you have access then `lsnrctl services` will show the registered services; if `orcl` isn't listed the database may be down, or may be unable to register for some reason, or is registering with a different service name. You can check the Windows services too.

Comment: @AlexPoole I use sql developer to do things in the database and I'm able to connect just fine there, which is weird because the last time this happened and when it happened to one of my coworkers, I couldn't connect through there either. It just doesn't work on the front end. I checked the services and orcl is the only one listed.

Comment: OK, well you haven't shown how you're connecting, or which client you're using. You said "I've checked on my command line and the service name is correct" which sounds like you aren't using a TNS alias.

Comment: It looks like you have some listener parameters in your tnsnames.ora. Could you post your listener.ora if any?